# Formatting numpy arrays with black

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am using vscode along with black as a formatter. I don't like how it formats numpy arrays and how it is effected by line length, for example

```
F = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

versus

```
F = np.array(
        [
            [1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],
        ]
    )
```

For readability I prefer the latter, but black formats the latter style when the former style would violate the line length.

Is there a way to customize black to prefer formatting the latter style without changing the line length parameter.

I am open to other formatters, I am just using black because it interfaces nice with flake8. My line length is set to 88.

Comment: https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Black only have two configuration options:

1. Line length
2. Whether to replace `'` quotes with `"`

If you want this level of configuration you will probably want to look at autopep8 or yapf.

Comment: I have no particular preference for black. Do you have anhy recommendation on autopep8 vs yapf for this kind of customization with with flake8 s a linter?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any advice as I personally use Black.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use shadowing:

```
x = [
    [1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],
]

x = np.array(x)
```

Note that this works for any length of array since a trailing comma indicates to black that you do not want the block condensed to one line.

Of course, it would be nicer if we could avoid shadowing altogether:

```
x = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],
])
```

...but black [currently doesn't do that](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1811).

Answer (score 1):

A dirty yet effective workaround is to force black to keep the multiple lines by including a comment:

```py
x = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # comment left to force black's hand
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],
    ]
)
```

I know, I know.